# Blender Internal: normal map facing wrong on barrel mesh

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, normal-map

I made a barrel model from a Sphere and textured it normally, but the Normal map generated from the image (InsaneBump) looks displaced and weird. It shows some strange stuff, like **this**: [image]

Object mode: [image]

You see that the top is displaced and the sides look like the sides of a sphere. Different projections didn't change the result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you upload a .blend on blendswap? From those screenshots alone its a bit tough to figure out the problem^^

Comment: @Chris here it is [link](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/93566) :)